# How to identify a subset using a specific label

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set {1,2,3,4,5}, could we use a combination of some labels, for example the sum of elements in the subset or the average or anything else, to build a bijection between the subset and the combination of labels? I tried to use the **sum of elements in subsets**, **the number of elements** and **the median number** to build the bijection but failed. Because in {1,2,3,4,5} if we want to identify {1,3,5} using (9,3,3), it can be also referred to {2,3,4}.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? With five labels you could give all information.

Comment: Actually, I want to find the minimal combination, which means using the minimal number of labels to identify for all sizes of sets.

Comment: Does $\sum_{n\in\mathbb S} 2^n$ suit your needs?

Comment: Here is the problem. Given $\sum_{n\in\mathbb S} 2^n$, can you reconstruct the subset?